# POSTGRESQL - unnested ARRAY values not behaving as expected

Tags: arrays, postgresql, join

I need to unnest this array so I can join it with a list of IDs(integer)

```
CREATE TABLE studies  
( 
 study_id INTEGER,
 specialties TEXT[]
)
 WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);


CREATE TABLE specialties
(
specialty_id INTEGER,
specialty_text TEXT[]
)
 WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
```

STUDIES DATA

```
study_id    specialties 
2333    {}
2332    {}
2329    {'1635','1646'}     
2328    {}
2327    {'1643','1695','1696'}
```

SPECIALTIES DATA

```
specialty_id    specialty_text
1635        Nephrology
1643        General Surgery
1646        Nephrology
1692        Internal Medicine
1695        Neurology
```

Unnesting the array works fine using this query

```
select study_id, unnest(specialties) as spec_id
from studies
where study_id in (2333,2332,2330,2329)
```

Results

```
study_id        spec_id
2329        '1635'
2329        '1646'
2327        '1643'
2327        '1695'
2327        '1696'
```

I want to then join the below specialties table, to bring in the corresponding specialty text. However I seem to be having issue with the unnested values having single quotes ' wrapped around them.

I tried trim and ltrim

```
select study_id, trim(both '''' from unnest(specialties)) as spec_id
from studies
where study_id in (2333,2332,2330,2329,2328,2327,2318,2317)
```

But the results still appear exactly the same, single quotes not removed - any ideas to remove these so i can cast as integer or join with a numeric field?

```
study_id        spec_id
2329        '1635'
2329        '1646'
2329        '850761'
2329        '877725'
2329        '1664'
```

**UPDATE**

added table definitions and @CraigRinger I tried casting the array to integer, no luck

CAST ATTEMPT:

```
select study_id, unnest(specialties::integer) as spec_id
from studies
where study_id in (2333,2332,2330,2329,2328,2327,2318,2317)
```

RESULT:

```
ERROR: cannot cast type text[] to integer
SQL state: 42846
```

Comment: You *might* be running into this: http://www.mesoconcepts.com/2013/06/inconsistent-unnesting-in-postgresql/

Comment: Can you provide a short demo on sqlfiddle.com so that we can see the raw data?

Comment: You've used an array of `text` or `varchar`, i.e. `text[]`, not an array of integer `integer[]`.

Comment: @CraigRinger so you are suggesting this data was stored improper to begin with, considering they are supposed to be integer ID numbers (which is where they came from to be added to the array)

I guess I was hoping there was an easy way to unnest it as a numeric, even it was stored improperly as text

Comment: @hackg There is: `unnest(mycolumn::integer[])`. But it's better to fix the schema. I'm just *guessing* that that's the problem though... you should show your table definitions, otherwise all I can do is guess.

Comment: You need to show the `join` query.

Comment: You did not trim anything with `trim(both '' from ...)`: the proper escaping is `trim(both '''' from ...)` or `trim(both E'\'' from ...)` **if** you really have quotes in your values (this case, you cannot cast to it `int[]`, which is the preferred otherwise). Note that array input syntax for proper `text[]` values is `'{"234", "foo"}'` -- element values are quoted with double quotes.

Comment: `unnest(specialties::integer)` should be `unnest(specialties::integer[])` per @CraigRinger's comment.

Comment: @pozs you were right! I recalled proper escaping a single quote was to use two single quotes together, hence my trim(both '' from

But when I tried using 4 single quotes together, the ltrim worked. You were also right about it not casting to integer, but now that the quotes have been trimmed I can continue on with my JOIN, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This worked - thanks @pozs for pointing out my trim was incorrect and fixing that allowed me to cast as integer properly

```
select study_id, trim(both '''' from unnest(specialties))::integer as spec_id
from studies
where study_id in (2333,2332,2330,2329,2328,2327,2318,2317)
```

results

```
    study_id       spec_id  
   (integer)      (integer)  
    2329           1635
    2329           1646
    2327           1696
    2327           1643
    2327           1695
```